# Is there a way to create a shorcut to files using subversion? (windows)

Tags: svn

I was wondering if there is a way to create a shortcut to files using subversion.

the situation is like that:

My projects structures look something like that:

```
 \bin

    private_binary.exe
    public_binary.exe

 \documentation

    private_doc.doc
    public_doc.pfd

 \sources
    ...
```

When commiting a change - it is alsorequired to transfer only the public binaries/documentations to the QA team for testing. We are now doing that by simply coping the relevant files to a network drive owned by the QA.

My thoughts are to create a new folder within the project: QA. then, to create a shotcuts to the relevant public files

something like that:

```
 \bin
     private_binary.exe
     public_binary.exe
 \sources\
     private_doc.doc
     public_doc.pfd

  \QA
     shortcut to public_binary.exe
     shortcut to public_doc.pdf
```

this way, the QA team will just have to go to the \QA folder of the latest revision and and will have safe access to the correct files.

is it possible? if not, I'll glad to hear any workarounds/ how do you publish your stuff to the QA teams.

Many Thanks,

Ofer

Comment: JFYI - storing build artifacts, not sources, considered as bad practice in SCM. Build-agents must build and deliver such objects (in ideal world).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation under svn:externals which is probably the in-built facility closest to what you are asking for.   Like you I'll be interested to learn what others are doing.

Comment: thanks mark. indeed this is the solution i looked for. 
here is the external property value is set on the qa folder:

../trunk/sources/trunk_file.txt qa/trunk_file.txt

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) that exports the binaries and the documentation in the QA network drive.

Comment: that's more or less is what i'm doing now. i thought it will be nice to let the QA a direct subversion access for the public files - this will save the error-prone network copy operations.